# adding days to historical dates in app script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, math

I am trying to pull some historical data, which has a variety of time stamps. I want the use to a user selected date, and then pull all days + some additional days.
Date1 is

```
var Date1 = "Thu Oct 22 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020"
var startDate = new Date(Date1)

var Enddate = new Date();
Enddate.setDate(startDate + 10);
```

This doesn't work. I cant seem to figure out how to add the "10 days" to the Date1 variable.

Comment: "This doesn't work." What does that mean? Do you get an error? Is the date different from what you imagined it should be?

Comment: the log i get for Enddate is:  Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 GMT-05:00 1969 , which is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `getDate` function of the `Date` object, *and* you'll need to pass the correct value when instantiating the new `Date`.

Try this:

```
var Date1 = "Thu Oct 22 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020"
var startDate = new Date(Date1);
// add it to startDate, using getDate()
startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 10);

// now startDate will be 10 days later:
startDate; // Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020

// if you want an entirely new Date object, then instantiate a new one:
var Enddate = new Date(startDate);
```

If you want two different variables, ***then*** you can use the approach similar to what you tried, like so:

```
var Date1 = "Thu Oct 22 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020"
var startDate = new Date(Date1), second = new Date(Date1);      // we're using another temporary variable

// add the days
second.setDate(second.getDate() + 10);
// now use Enddate with this
var Enddate = new Date(second);

Enddate; // Sun Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020
```

Comment: fantastic! this worked exactly as needed. Didn't realize I needed to use the getDate() after the variable

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add a number to a `Date` object to get a new date.

You can add to a date by:

1. getting the current day of the month with `getDate()`
2. adding a number of days to that result
3. setting the new date with `setDate()`

```js
const Date1 = "Thu Oct 22 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2020";
const addDays = 10;

const startDate = new Date(Date1);
const startDays = startDate.getDate();

const newDate = new Date(startDate);
newDate.setDate(startDays + addDays);

console.log('startDate:', startDate.toISOString());
console.log('newDate:', newDate.toISOString());
```

**Note:**

Passing a string into the `Date` constructor is [discouraged](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Timestamp_string), as it produces inconsistent results across browsers.

It is better to pass in the individual date and time values:

```js
const Date1 = new Date(2020, 9, 22, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Adding a day by adding 24 hours isn't a good idea because where daylight saving is observed, not all days are 24 hours long. See the duplicate.